# Truncate report_event table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, log, data-migration

Can I truncate report_event table in Magento 2?

I am migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and I find that report_event table has too many records which will slow down the migration process.

**Is it safe to truncate the report_event table?**

**What is the consequences of the truncation of data ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try!

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
```

You can also refer to following tutorial:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/article/log-cache-maintenance-script/

Thanks